# solr4.0, wrong hostname when there is a dot

Tags: solr, cloud, cluster-computing, hostname

I am building a full distributed solr cluster on different servers, the servers are `server1.mycompany.com` and `server2.mycompany.com`. after configuration when I click `server1.mycompany.com` in web console, solr try to connect  `server1:8983/solr` rather than `server1.mycompany.com:8983/solr`. And I use java API:

```
ZkStateReader zkStateReader = cloudQuery.getCloudSolrServer().getZkStateReader();
ClusterState clusterState = zkStateReader.getClusterState();
System.out.println(clusterState);
```

I still get `"node_name":"server1:8983_solr","base_url":"http://server1:8983/solr"`.

anyone give a hint? is this a bug or something to be configured?

Comment: seems solr use server alias rather than domain name, so I edit hosts file to make it workable